# Counting the characters in strings within a list, Python

Tags: python

I am having difficulty with one of my homework questions.

Basically, I am to create a function using a for loop to count the characters used in strings which are inside of a list. I am able to get the length of the strings with len(), but I can only get one of the strings and I can't seem to get it in list form.

My Code:

```
def method1(input1):

    total = 0

    a = []

    for word in input1:

        total = len(word)

        a = [total]

    return a
```

This returns [3] with the input ['seven', 'one']

Any help would be appreciated. I am very new to Python.

Comment: `return sum([len(a) for a in input1])`

Comment: all you need to do is `a += [total]` . this returns the length of strings in a list form. So if your input is `['Seven', 'one']`. It will return ` [5,3]`

Comment: @Digvijayad That did the trick! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Well here is one way of doing it. You have list "a" with different strings inside of them. You can simply iterate through the list counting the `len`gth of each string.

```
def method1(input1):

    l = list(input1)
    total = sum(len(i) for i in l)
    return int(total)

print(method1(["hello", "bye"]))
```

What you are doing here is receiving an input and converting it to a list. Then for each value inside of the list, you are calculating it's length. The `sum` adds up those lengths and finally, you return `total`.

Comment: You don't need `int(total)` it is already an `int`. You also don't need `l` - `for i in input1` would be sufficient - this just boils down to `return sum(len(i) for i in input1)` or `return sum(map(len, input1))`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!